# Can you log both XC PIC time and simulated instrument time together?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, pic

Are you permitted to log both XC PIC time as well as simulated instrument time (during the voyage over) whilst with a qualified safety pilot? I am pursuing my IR and would like to know if doing this is a useful strategy to build some hours in both required categories.

(I realize both pilots cannot log PIC **XC** time. Only one pilot can perform the necessary landing 50+ nm from the origin airfield in order to get the time there.)

Comment: Yes. As well as PIC: SEL, Day VFR.

Comment: I added the faa-regulations tag, if you're asking about another country then please re place it with an appropriate tag for that country. When you ask about regulations, please *always* tell us which country you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can log XC, PIC, simulated instrument, category/class, day/night, Total flight time.

From a regulation standpoint.
Cross time can be logged pursuant to [§61.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.1)

> Cross-country time means -
>
> Except as provided in paragraphs (ii) through (vi) of this definition, time acquired during flight -
>
> > (A) Conducted by a person who holds a pilot certificate;
> >
> > (B) Conducted in an aircraft;
> >
> > (C) That includes a landing at a point other than the point of departure; and
> >
> > (D) That involves the use of dead reckoning, pilotage, electronic navigation aids, radio aids, or other navigation systems to navigate to the landing point.
>
> For the purpose of meeting the aeronautical experience requirements (except for a rotorcraft category rating), for a private pilot certificate (except for a powered parachute category rating), a commercial pilot certificate, or an **instrument rating**, or for the purpose of exercising recreational pilot privileges (except in a rotorcraft) under § 61.101 (c), time acquired during a flight -
>
> > (A) Conducted in an appropriate aircraft;
> >
> > (B) **That includes a point of landing that was at least a straight-line distance of more than 50 nautical miles from the original point of departure**; and
> >
> > (C) That involves the use of dead reckoning, pilotage, electronic navigation aids, radio aids, or other navigation systems to navigate to the landing point.

---

PIC time can be logged pursuant to [§61.51(e)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.51)

> (e) Logging pilot-in-command flight time.
>
> > (1) A sport, recreational, private, commercial, or airline transport pilot may log pilot in command flight time for flights-
> >
> > > (i) Except when logging flight time under § 61.159(c), when the pilot is the **sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which the pilot is rated**, or has sport pilot privileges for that category and class of aircraft, if the aircraft class rating is appropriate;

---

All others are logged as a requirement under [§61.51(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.51)